# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: angular

data-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], query: string): any {

    if (!query || query === '') {
      return array;
    }

    let filtered = [];
    array.forEach(function (element) {
      let isAdded = false;
      Object.keys(element).forEach(function (key, index) {
        if (!isAdded && element[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
          filtered.push(element);
          isAdded = true;
        }
      });
    });

    return filtered;
  }

}
```

in .html

```
<table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]="users | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: you invoke toString method only at one place in your code. That means, the object on which you call the method is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means that your value for some key `element[key]` is `undefined`. You need to add one more check for *truthy*

```
!isAdded && element[key] && element[key].toString()...
// ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I saw in the code:

1- whenever you are going through Object keys, make sure you are testing
   the intended keys (unless you don't want that) by using `hasOwnProperty`

2- you only have one `toString()` usage in the code you posted, and from the 
   error, you know exactly what it is, can't call the function on `undefined` 
   therefore `element[key]` is undefined.
   Notice, the key exists but the value doesn't, you can solve this in many ways, 
   like @sauren suggested, you can add it in the if statement, or make sure you 
   set it to an empty string before you call the function on it, or whatever you 
   see fit.
   But the idea is the same, make sure the value is not undefined before you use it to call the function.